# Stackoverflow.com sends me 502

Tags: bug, connectivity

When trying to connect to stackoverflow.com I get the message:

```
502 Bad Gateway

The server returned an invalid or incomplete response.
```

This is going on for some hours now. The same thing occurs about once in a week for a few hours.

I tried incognito mode, another browser or my phone. When my phone was not connected to my WLAN I suddenly could connect. Switched back to WLAN and 502 again.

I found that this could be a problem with websockets on some proxy, but a browser test confirmed websockets port 80 was working.

So has this something to do with my ISP? Is this a known problem?

---

Edit:

Ok... It just happened again. After resetting my router it was working again! I always leave the site open all day. Maybe this is corrupting my router?! This can't all be working as intended. This is only happening on the site stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Works fine here. Have you tried resetting your network settings?

Comment: @ColeJohnson I know the site is not down for everyone. I can connect again now. It doesn't seem like there is anything wrong on my end, but on the connection between me and stackoverflow. I didn't change anything between working and not working.

Comment: Did you try to reboot your PC? It helped for me the one time it happened to me.

Comment: While I shudder to link it, [this is actually a pretty comprehensive help file on the subject](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm).

Comment: @JanDvorak I wrote in the post that I tried connecting with my phone. So the problem has to be somewhere from my router to stackoverflow. I can't think of anything that would happen temporarily with my router though. I can connect to any other side.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Thanks, I'm falling through to points 11 and 12 though. While I doubt that it is the cause I can try to reset my router the next time it happens.

Comment: It could very well be - many consumer and prosumer routers have trouble keeping a lot of concurrent connections open, and will occasionally screw up their ARP tables internally. A hard reset (5 seconds off) will actually fix it, I've encountered this on Linksys/Cisco and Netgear routers. Websockets complicate this because they actually **need** to keep concurrent connections open.

Comment: You say the problem is your _phone_? Could it be that your phone isn't connected to the Wi-Fi in your house and the data connection isn't working (or you don't have one)?

Comment: @ColeJohnson No, sorry if I was unclear somewhere. The only way I could access stackoverflow was on my phone via data connection. All attempted browsers/devices that were connected through my home connection (including my phone on wi-fi) failed.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes see my edit. Do you want to write this as answer?

Comment: Done and made complete for reference sake - good to hear it helped  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could very well be just a local router issue - many consumer and prosumer routers have trouble keeping a lot of concurrent connections open, and will occasionally screw up their ARP tables internally. A hard reset (5 seconds off) will actually fix it, I've encountered this on Linksys/Cisco and Netgear routers. Websockets complicate this because they actually **need** to keep concurrent connections open.

If this does **not** solve it, try this [step-by-step guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/502error.htm) on debugging the problem. On a site the size of Stack Overflow it's always safer to assume a local problem than a remote one - a million concurrent users tend to be vocal about their problems.

As for a structural solution - SO isn't doing anything out of the ordinary with its use of websockets and Ajax, it's just doing a lot of it so you tend to notice it faster if things occasionally go wrong. Not much you can do about that except upgrading the firmware on your router or buying a more recent model.